# Inverted triangle in Java

Tags: java

I was trying to make an inverted triangle in java but I don't know what's wrong with my code

```
public void Tr1(int height, int begin, int pos, char ch){
    for (int i = 0;i < height;i++){
        for (int k = height;k > height - 1 - i;k--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0;j < pos;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int v = 0;v < i*2+begin;v++){
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
**
 ****
  ******
   ********
    **********
     ************
      **************
       ****************
        ******************
         ********************
```

And I want this

```
*******************
 *               *
  *             *
   *           *
    *         *
     *       *
      *     *
       *   *
        * *
         *
```

Comment: well, what is the error that you see?

Comment: Is your code working? Or is there an error? If there isn't an error, can you show us the output that you are getting now?

Comment: Presumably if the triangle is inverted, you are supposed to print less stars on the earlier lines. You're printing more stars are the earlier lines and less on the later lines.

Comment: It's working but i don't get a inverted triangle as you can see on the screnshoot

Comment: Could you create a screenshot that contains your expected result?

Comment: Isn't that triangle the same as Gosu and Master Slave mentioned??

Comment: See my explanation below for equilateral triangles and spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many similar questions have been asked, one for example [I'm having trouble making a diamond shape with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459514/im-having-trouble-making-a-diamond-shape-with-loops/26461085#26461085)

I posted a recursive answer, that can easily be adapted to your case

```
public class InvertedTriangle {
    static int iteration = 0;
    public static void printDiamond(int n) {
        int numberOfBlanks = n - iteration;
        int numberOfStars = iteration * 2 + 1;
        String blank = new String(new char[numberOfBlanks]).replace("\0", " ");
        String star = new String(new char[numberOfStars]).replace("\0", "*");
        String row = blank + star + blank;

        iteration++;
        if (iteration < n) {
            printDiamond(n);
        }
        // printing the rows backward
        System.out.println(row);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDiamond(5);
    }
}
```

This prints the

```
 ********* 
  *******  
   *****   
    ***    
     *
```

UPDATE after you question edit

```
public class InvertedTriangle {
    static int iteration = 0;

    public static void printDiamond(int n) {
        int numberOfBlanks = n - iteration;
        int numberOfInnerBlanks = iteration > 0 ? iteration * 2 - 1 : 0;
        String blank = new String(new char[numberOfBlanks]).replace("\0", " ");
        String innerBlank = new String(new char[numberOfInnerBlanks]).replace("\0", " ");
        String star = "*";
        String row = iteration == n - 1 ? blank + new String(new char[n * 2 - 1]).replace("\0", "*") + blank : iteration > 0 ? blank + star + innerBlank + star + blank : blank + star + blank;

        iteration++;
        if (iteration < n) {
            printDiamond(n);
        }
        // printing the rows backward
        System.out.println(row);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDiamond(10);
    }
}
```

This prints the

```
 ******************* 
  *               *  
   *             *   
    *           *    
     *         *     
      *       *      
       *     *       
        *   *        
         * *         
          *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go?

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int height = 9; // Height of triangle
    char ch = '*';

    for(int currHeight = 0; currHeight <= height; currHeight++)
    {
        for(int space = 0; space < currHeight; space++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        int requiredStars = (height - currHeight) * 2 + 1;
        for(int stars = 0; stars < requiredStars; stars++)
        {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

You just have to manipulate the variables used in the for loops.
It is not easy trying to guess what type of triangle you need.

Use better variable naming conventions rather than `j, k, v`

Comment: I want a proper triangle not this one.

Comment: What is a proper triangle??

Comment: That is what I saw in your linked image, which happens to be a broken link now.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop can be rewritten, as `k` is not further used.

```
for (int k = height; k > height - 1 - i; k--) {
for (int k = 0; k > - 1 - i; k--) {
for (int k = 0; k < 1 + i; ++k) {
```

But you mean the inverse, decreasing the indentation:

```
for (int k = 0; k < height - 1 - i; ++k) {
```

were i maximally will be height - 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method draw() and call:

```
public class Triangle{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Triangle.draw(5, "*");

        }

    public static void draw (int height, String st){
        for (int i=0; height>i; height--){
            System.out.println(new String(new char[height]).replace("\0", st));
        }
    }


    }
```

Result:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Late to the party & well, pretty sure that is not what he wants.. Truth is, we don't really know what he wants either!

Comment: Maybe, but at last i get a try :D

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an upside-down equilateral triangle using the method `draw()` below.

Of course, this is not a true equilateral triangle because although all sides have the same number of asterisks. Monospace characters have an average width-height ratio of 3:5.

```
* * *
 * *
  *
```

#### DrawTriangle.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class DrawTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(draw("*", 10));
    }

    public static String draw(String symbol, int side) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Top line
        for (int i = side; i > 0; i--){
            sb.append(symbol + " ");
        }
        sb.append("\n");

        // Sides
        for (int i = side-2; i > 0; i--){
            // Left Side
            for (int j = 1; j < side-i; j++) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append(symbol);

            // Right Side
            for (int k = 1; k <= (i * 2)- 1 ; k++) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append(symbol).append("\n");
        }

        // Bottom point
        for (int i = side-1; i > 0; i--) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.append(symbol).append("\n").toString();
    }
}
```

Output

```
* * * * * * * * * * 
 *               *
  *             *
   *           *
    *         *
     *       *
      *     *
       *   *
        * *
         *
```